# PowerShell, Open IE without Add-ons

Tags: powershell, comobject, com-object

I want to open the Internet Explorer as a new Com Object with no Add-ons.

$ie=New-Object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application

How could I start the Internet Explorer without Add-ons?

Answer (score 4):

It's even easier than that (assuming PowerShell 2.0 for Start-Process cmdlet):

```
Start-Process iexplore.exe -ArgumentList -extoff
```

See this page on [Internet Explorer command line options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330728(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: True, but how does one retrieve the reference to the ComObject? Using `Get-Process` lacks all the methods and properties that the OP's `$ie` object contains.  Seems like you only answered half the question.